# How can I render percent encoding in command line?

Tags: ubuntu, unicode, sed, command-line-interface

I often have a string "percent encoded", such as `%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB`, which, if it's part of a link, a modern browser would properly render as `файл`.

I wonder: is there a simple way to "render" a text file with percent encoding (or simply an input string in percent encoding) as the one above by using `sed` or other command line tool?

See also [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14078659/how-can-i-render-utf-16be-in-command-line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python can do this using `urllib.unquote_plus`:

```python
#!/usr/bin/env python2

import sys
import urllib

print urllib.unquote_plus("%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB")
```

You can set an alias to have a quick cli command:
http://ruslanspivak.com/2010/06/02/urlencode-and-urldecode-from-a-command-line/

Comment: Excellent, thank you! Any quick way of parsing a text file with some of these percent encodings mixed in, and having it change only them? Like a find and replace?

Comment: `unquote_plus` only decodes `%XX` and also `+` to spaces. You can apply it to a whole text file. If it contains `+` you want to keep, you can also use plain `unquote`: http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#utility-functions

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Python, can you tell what command you would apply to a text file instead of a string?

Comment: You can open a file with [open(filename, 'r')](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files), then you can iterate on its lines with `for line in f:` (like shown in the link) and apply unquote separately on each line. You will also want to close the file at the end.