# How can I render UTF-16BE in command line?

Tags: ubuntu, unicode, sed, command-line-interface

I often come across a string representing UTF-16BE, such as `\u0444\u0430\u0439\u043b`, which would be properly rendered as `файл`.

I wonder: is there a simple way to "render" a text file in UTF-16BE (or simply an input string in in UTF-16BE) such as the one above by using sed or other command line tool?

See also [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14078628/how-can-i-render-percent-encoding-in-command-line).

Comment: Is the string actually encoded in UTF-16BE, with 2 bytes per Unicode character, or is it an ASCII string with backslash characters as you've shown in your question?

Comment: That string is not UTF-16BE. Please update your question.

Comment: If I understand your `"render"` notation, you mean a simple way to translate the six-byte escape sequence into a UTF-16BE character, in addition to being able to _actually_ render on the console. You can do this with a script or small program that selectively interprets JSON string character escapes. I'd happily take less than an hour to write such a procedure if this is the only notation being "rendered". For it to work _in your case_ it largely depends on the answer to Keith Thompson's question.  Please elaborate your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the text is actually encoded in UTF-16BE (and not, as you show in your question, as an ASCII string containing backslash and `'u'` characters), you can use the `iconv` command.

Assuming your locale is set to handle UTF-8 output:

```
iconv -f utf-16be -t utf-8 [input-file]
```

**EDIT :**

Based on your comments, what you have is not UTF-16BE at all; it's apparently plain ASCII, encoding Unicode code points using the `\u....` syntax. This is not a format that `iconv` recognizes (as far as I know).

You should edit your question, removing any references to UTF-16BE and explaining more accurately what data you actually have, and what you want to do with it. Where did these strings come from? Are they stored in a text file, or did they come from some other source (say, the output of some program)? Does the input consist *entirely* of `\u....`, or is it mixed with other data? And are your locale settings configured to display UTF-8 properly?

If you have a string containing `"\u0444\u0430\u0439\u043b"` (that's 24 ASCII characters), then the `printf` command should work -- *if* you use a sufficiently recent version of `printf`.

`printf` is both a shell built-in and an external command, `/usr/bin/printf`, part of the GNU coreutils package.

The following works on my system:

```
$ s='\u0444\u0430\u0439\u043b'
$ printf "$s\n"
файл
```

Or you can use the `%b` format (this is specific to the `printf` command; C's `printf()` function doesn't do this), which interprets backslash escapes in argument strings (normally they're only interpreted in the format string):

```
$ printf "%b\n" "$s"
файл
```

On another system, with an older version of bash, the `printf` builtin doesn't recognize `\u` escapes -- but `/usr/bin/printf` does. It appears that the coreutils `printf` command gained support for `\u` escapes earlier than bash did.

```
$ s='\u0444\u0430\u0439\u043b'
$ printf "$s\n"
\u0444\u0430\u0439\u043b
$ printf "%b\n" "$s"
\u0444\u0430\u0439\u043b
$ /usr/bin/printf "$s\n"
файл
$ /usr/bin/printf "%b\n" "$s"
файл
```

All of this assumes you have the `'\u0444\u0430\u0439\u043b'` string in a variable. If it's in a file, you *could* slurp the file contents into a shell variable, probably a line at a time, but it's not the best solution. In that case, this Perl script should do the job; it copies its input to stdout, replacing `\u....` sequences with the corresponding Unicode character, encoded in UTF-8; the input can be either one or more files named on the command line, or standard input if it's invoked with no arguments.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use utf8;
binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");

while (<>) {
    s/\\u([\da-fA-F]{4})/chr(hex($1))/eg;
    print;
}
```

Again, *please* edit your question so it reflects your actual problem and drops any references to UTF-16BE.

Comment: It's UTF-16BE but each is preceded by an `\u`, just as my example. Is there another name for that?

Comment: If you have' for example, 6 bytes with the values `'\'`, `'u'`, `'0'`, `'4'`, `'4'`, `'4'`, that's not UTF-16BE; it's plain ASCII that happens to be a human-readable representation of a Unicode code point. The UTF-16BE representation of that same code point would be exactly 2 bytes, with the values `'0x04'`, `'0x44'`. If you have a *file* containing UTF-16BE, try examining it with a hex editor or dump command; such files are commonly created on MS Windows.

Comment: Got it. In my case it is in string form, only. Any solutions when it's a text like this?  `\u0444\u0430\u0439\u043b`?  The `printf` and `echo -e` didn't  work.

Comment: @Strapakowsky: See my updated answer -- and please update your question.

Answer (score 1):

Simply do:

```
echo -e "\u0444\u0430\u0439\u043b"
```

Notice you may need to set your env variable `LANG` to `utf-8`:

```
export LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
```

As pointed by Keith Thompson, it may be even better to use `printf`; so, you'd have:

```
printf "\u0444\u0430\u0439\u043b"
```

And for the two above options, the output is:

```
файл
```

Comment: `echo -e` hasn't always had that capability. The `printf` command is more likely to work.

Comment: And you're assuming the input is ASCII containing backslashes and `'u'` characters, which I suspect is not the case.

Comment: Isn't this the data the OP provided?

Comment: None of them worked for me. The output is the same as the input. Am I missing anything?

Comment: you may be looking for the answer provided by Keith Thompson